# Error in sphinx helloworld code

Tags: java, eclipse, cmusphinx

I am trying to set up sphinx, i am following [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GeqtLrcOogs) tutorial.
When i copy and paste the code of hello world from "sphinx4-0.1alpha-src"; i get an error on line:

```
} catch (InstantiationException e) {
```

> Error says Unreachable catch block for InstantiationException.

This exception is never thrown from the try statement body.
I mean i have not written this code, and even in the video there is this line but no error comes up. I know that it is not a big deal and if i run the program and click avoid the error, it runs properly.
[image]
[I am using Eclipse "eclipse-standard-kepler-SR1-win32-x86_64" on a windows 8 machine]

List of files in that folder:
build.xml
hello.gram
helloworld.config.xml
HelloWorld.java
helloworld.Manifest
README.html

Ques - why do i see this error at all?
(I think there is not a problem in the code as it is alpha edition of sphnix)

Comment: that exception could be subclass of one of the two above catched exception type, post the link to javadoc

Comment: http://pastebin.com/LxuMihFx

Comment: where is InstantiationException ?

Comment: What do you mean? it is there at the end of that file... :P i am a newbie

Comment: @sᴜʀ I don't see that imported in pastebin link he posted

Comment: @JigarJoshi Oh. Sorry. I misunderstood.

Comment: @JigarJoshi i added a list of files in the folder, which file did you need? i have just given you HelloWorld.java

Comment: @sᴜʀ it is default imported one of those lang class

Comment: @Dak see answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be because this exception is never declared to be thrown from your `try{}` block, just remove last catch block

Comment: Well, i already thought that the code would work if i remove that block because if i run it right now it works, my question is that maybe i am doing something wrong because the same code doesnt seem to show up any problems in that video... are you sure that the code has bug in it?

Comment: i don't know about that video tutorial, if your code doesn't declare to throw that non runtime exception  you shuoldn't be catching it

Comment: So you mean to say that the code is incorrect (for sure) and i should delete that block right?

Comment: yes <!----> _if your code doesn't declare to throw that non runtime exception you shouldn't be expecting it_